# Does Raspberry Pi 4 processor support AES-NI instructions?

Tags: pi-4, vpn, security, arm, encryption

In the interest of minimizing [timing attacks](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/05/aes_timing_atta_1.html) on my OpenVPN and similar connections, does Raspberry Pi 4 support [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) instructions?

Some reference to AES is made in the [technical reference manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100095_0003_06_en/cortex_a72_mpcore_trm_100095_0003_06_en.pdf), but I don't see a conclusive answer anywhere.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the answer. Any reason why you didn't post that as answer with links?

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1488643/does-raspberry-pi-4-support-aes-hardware-acceleration

Answer (score 10):

The Raspberry Pi 4 does not have cryptographic extensions, to be more precise it has, but to be enabled would require HW changes alongside paying a license to Broadcom/ARM.

Here's the link for a discussion on RPi's forum where a RPi *foundation* engineer explains the fuzz: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=207888

jamesh's answer is straight forward:

> That is licence for the HW, so you buy it then add the requisite HW to the die, so no, it cannot be added later without redeisgning the HW, which would cost about $1M Plus the licence....